# How to embed fullscreen image into google slides

Tags: google-slides

I want to embed a slideshow that goes from edge to edge of the screen. It would be convenient if I could embed into the header, but it only accepts images, and no embeds or zip files.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want a background image. On the toolbar, select View, then Master. You'll see a 'background' option on the toolbar.